# Dúvida com sintaxe

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-pattern, sintaxe

Dúvida simples. Geralmente eu vejo essa sintaxe:

```
require('../lib/dbconnect')(config);
```

Mas fico sem entender o motivo de usar esses parênteses dessa forma

```
(....)(....);
```

Alguém pode me explicar do que se trata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa sintaxe `require('../lib/dbconnect')(config);` usa-se quando o módulo precisa de ser configurado.

Ou seja, no código do módulo há algo como:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function (options) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: options.url,
        user: options.user,
        password: options.pass,
        database: options.database
    });
    connection.connect();

    return connection.query; // que é uma função
}
```

Isso é muito comum quando se quer passar uma `url`, chave secreta, ip da base de dados, tradução ou outro para um módulo.

Depois de configurado usa-se como normalmente:

```
var db = require('../lib/dbconnect')(config);
db.query('SELECT * FROM tabela', function(err, dados){
    // etc
});
```

**Um exemplo em JavaScript não necessáriamente em ambiente Node** seria um conversor de velocidade, foi o que me ocorreu agora! :P

```
function velocidade(conf){
    return function(KmHora){
        var velocidade = typeof KmHora == 'number' ? KmHora : parseInt(KmHora, 10);
        var ms = velocidade * conf.fator;
        return [ms, conf.unidade].join(' ');
    }
}
```

Assim podemos configurar a unidade, e o fator de multiplicação.

```
var converter = velocidade({unidade:'m/s', fator: 1/3.6});
```

E depois usar a função em *n* valores diferentes:

```
console.log(converter('300 km/h')); // 83.33333333333334 m/s
console.log(converter(116)); // 32.(2) m/s
console.log(converter(36)); // 10 m/s
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3hrk5u7/

Comment: Ahh sim... entendi. Isso no caso é exclusivo do Node.js? Ou esse comportamento "estranho" é reproduzido também em bibliotecas que funcionam no client-side?

Comment: @PedroVinícius pode ser usado em qualquer linguagem que permita retornar funções e/ou onde o escopo dos argumentos da primeira função passe para o escopo interno. Independentemente de ser client- ou server-side

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo feito em JavaScript puro fora do Node.js? Achei interessante...

Comment: @PedroVinícius por exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/b3hrk5u7/, ou o modelo de Classe tem a mesma ideia `var luis = new Animal('humano');``

Comment: Opa! Muito obrigado! Entendi como esse negócio funciona hehe

Answer (score 6):

É equivalente a fazer isso aqui:

```
var db = require('../lib/dbconnect');
db(config);
```

A função require retorna o valor exportado no arquivo dbconnect.js. Essse módulo exportou uma única função, que você está chamando passando config como parâmetro.